# Getting null from the seda queue

Tags: apache-camel, junit4

I have a camel route that looks like this:

```xml
 <camel:camelContext id="context" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
        <propertyPlaceholder id="camelContextProperties" location="ref:lefrogen"/>
        <contextScan/>
        <template id="producerTemplate"/>
        <template id="consumerTemplate"/>
        <route id="chibzo">
            <from uri="activemq:queueName"/>
            <to uri="seda:internal?multipleConsumers=true"/>
        </route>
        <route id="chon">
            <from uri="seda:internal?multipleConsumers=true"/>
            <bean ref="beanName"/>
            <to uri="seda:external?multipleConsumers=true"/>
        </route>
    </camel:camelContext>
```

The bean class is like this:

```java
@Component
public class BeanName {
    private final static Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(BeanName.class.getName());
    public static String message = null;

    public static String map(String custom) {    
        message = custom;
        return custom;
    }       

}
```

I have written a unit test which is supposed to get the data from the bean and then compare it with the data from `seda:external`. The problem is that I am getting null when I am fetching data from the seda queue. Here's the unit test:

```java
public class Test{
  @EndpointInject
  ProducerTemplate producerTemplate;

  @EndpointInject
  ConsumerTemplate consumerTemplate;

  @Autowired
  BeanName beanName; 

  @Test
  public void testName() throws Exception {   
    producerTemplate.sendBody("seda:internal","Good bye");

    Thread.sleep(10000); //needs to sleep so that the bean gets executed before accessing 
                         //beanName.message;

    String message = beanName.message;
    LOGGER.info("Printing" + message); //prints (Good bye)

    String body = consumerTemplate.receiveBodyNoWait("seda:external", String.class);
    LOGGER.info("Body is" + body); //prints null 
  }
```

Any reason why the queue is giving `null`?

Answer (score 0):

Its due concurrent, and you are using recieveBodyNoWait which does a fast check. Instead use receiveBody and provide may a timeout value to avoid waiting if there is no messages on the queue.

Or add sleep in the code if you want to use receiveBodyNoWait still.

Comment: what do you mean by "its due concurrent" ? Also, if I use receiveBody, it gets stuck on consumerTemplate.receiveBody because there is nothing on the queue.Also, you meantioned that I should use sleep in my code when using receiveBodyNoWait, which I am already doing. :)..